# wglCreateContext fails with error code 6 (Invalid Handle)

Tags: windows, opengl, d

I'm trying to create a wgl context according to the tutorial at https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL). For whatever reason, `wglCreateContext` returns `null`, and `GetLastError` returns `6`, or Invalid Handle. I have used the tutorial before, and it worked just fine.

I'm trying to create a dummy context to a hidden window so that I can create another context for the user window. What's going on?

The Windows API is referred through the `winAPI` identifier, and `wgl` is a global struct containing function pointers to OpenGL.

```
struct WglContext
{
    winAPI.HDC hdc;
    winAPI.HGLRC handle;
}

__gshared Win32GL wgl;

///WGL-specific global data.
struct Win32GL
{
    import oswald : OsWindow, WindowConfig, WindowError;

    OsWindow helperWindow;
    winAPI.HINSTANCE instance;

    PFN_wglCreateContext createContext;
    PFN_wglDeleteContext deleteContext;
    PFN_wglGetProcAddress getProcAddress;
    PFN_wglMakeCurrent makeCurrent;

    PFN_wglCreateContextAttribsARB createContextAttribsARB;
    PFN_wglGetExtensionStringARB getExtensionStringARB;
    PFN_wglGetExtensionStringEXT getExtensionStringEXT;

    bool extensionsAreLoaded;

    static void initialize()
    {
        if (wgl.instance !is null)
            return; //The library has already been initialized

        WindowConfig cfg;
        cfg.title = "viewport_gl_helper";
        cfg.hidden = true;
        auto windowError = OsWindow.createNew(cfg, &wgl.helperWindow);
        if (windowError != WindowError.NoError)
        {
            import std.conv : to;

            assert(false, "Failed to create helper window: " ~ windowError.to!string);
        }

        wgl.instance = winAPI.LoadLibrary("opengl32.dll");

        if (wgl.instance is null)
            assert(false, "Viweport failed to load opengl32.dll");

        wgl.bind(cast(void**)&wgl.createContext, "wglCreateContext\0");
        wgl.bind(cast(void**)&wgl.deleteContext, "wglDeleteContext\0");
        wgl.bind(cast(void**)&wgl.getProcAddress, "wglGetProcAddress\0");
        wgl.bind(cast(void**)&wgl.makeCurrent, "wglMakeCurrent\0");
    }

    static void terminate()
    {
        if (!wgl.instance)
            return;

        winAPI.FreeLibrary(wgl.instance);
        wgl.helperWindow.destroy();
    }

    void bind(void** func, in string name)
    {
        *func = winAPI.GetProcAddress(this.instance, name.ptr);
    }
}

struct WglContext
{
    winAPI.HDC hdc;
    winAPI.HGLRC handle;
}

WglContext wglCreateTmpContext()
{
    assert(wgl.instance);

    winAPI.PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    pfd.nSize = winAPI.PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR.sizeof;
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = winAPI.PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | winAPI.PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | winAPI.PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = winAPI.PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;

    auto hdc = winAPI.GetDC(wgl.helperWindow.platformData.handle);

    const pixelFormat = winAPI.ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
    if (winAPI.SetPixelFormat(hdc, pixelFormat, &pfd) == winAPI.FALSE)
        assert(false, "Failed to set pixel format for temp context");

    writeln(hdc);
    writeln(pixelFormat);

    winAPI.HGLRC context = wgl.createContext(hdc);
    if (context is null)
    {
        import std.conv: to;
        assert(false, "Failed to create temp context: Error Code " ~ winAPI.GetLastError().to!string);
    }

    if (wgl.makeCurrent(hdc, context) == winAPI.FALSE)
    {
        wgl.deleteContext(context);
        assert(false, "Failed to make temp context current");
    }

    return WglContext(hdc, context);
}

void main()
{
    wgl.initialize(); //Fetches function pointers, and loads opengl32.dll
    auto context = wglCreateTmpContext();
    wglDeleteContext(context); //Delegates to wgl.deleteContext
    wgl.terminate(); //Unloads opengl32.dll and nulls function pointers
}
```

Comment: The "meet" in your issue is `wgl`, but you don't show it. How `hdc` is created and stored in `wgl`? Other issue: initialize **all** `pfd` fields to zero (and then set the ones used) or `ChoosePixelFormat` may fail.

Comment: D automatically zeros all variables on declaration. Also, I changed `wglCreateTmpContext` to get the `HDC` from the window handle.

Comment: If the error is "invalid handle" then dig on window creation and getting a valid `hdc`from it. BTW, for a temp context (used just to retrieve Windows API function pointers like `wglChoosePixelFormatARB`) any valid pixelformat suffices, you may use "1"..

Comment: My window is made according to their tutorial (ie. with `OWN_DC` flag set). I was under the impression that an incorrectly created window would return `null` from `GetDC`?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing on that `winAPI` you use. Anyhow, I'm sure of:

You must:

1. Create a window and get its `HWND` handle (Windows definition of
   HWND, see below). Tipically the window uses `WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`
   style; but try also the `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` as in the link you
   posted.
2. Verify you get a valid `HWND`, and a valid `HDC` from it.

`HWND` and `HDC` are defined as `*void`. I would not trust on `auto`.

Comment: `winAPI` is an alias (`import winAPI = core.sys.windows.windows`). I use the same function to create the hidden window, and the user-facing window. I can show/hide it as needed.

How to do you verify a `HWND` or `HDC`? I just know to check for `!null`

Comment: Does your window create function returns a `HWND`? It should. Don't confuse a `HWND` with a `HINSTANCE`

Comment: Yes, `HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(...);`

Comment: Being `hwnd` not NULL, then use `HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd)` That's the hdc needed for context.

Comment: That's what I've been using... and `hdc` is non-null too. But `wglCreateContext` keeps spitting out `null`.